# OpenAI - Algorithm: Implement the extract function to extract database by making calls to query

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, autocomplete, extract

- This is a question asked by OpenAI and submission date has passed away so finally I can ask this because I am very curious to know the answer.

Question:

- You're on a website (such as Github!) with a text field which autocompletes usernames as you type. Under the hood, there's an API call which takes in the prefix of a username and then returns all usernames which start with that prefix, lexicographically sorted and truncated at 5 results.
- Your task is to use this API call to dump the entire user database, specifically:
- Implement the `extract` function in `autocomplete.py`. `extract` should return the whole user database, making calls to query under the hood.

Notes:

- You can assume all valid usernames are comprised of lowercase ASCII letters (a-z).
- Assume that queries to the API are expensive and should be minimized, but it's more important to have a correct answer and well-structured solution than an optimal answer.
- Below is the Started Code provided by the OpenAI

  ```
  def extract(query):
      """extract takes in a `query` API function (which returns the first 5 usernames, lexicographically sorted,
         that start with a prefix) and returns the sorted list of all usernames in the database.
         For example, the `query` function in provided in `main` works as 
         follows:

         query("a") #=> ["abracadara", "al", "alice", "alicia", "allen"]
         query("ab") #=> ["abracadara"]
         The following implementation would pass the assertion in `main`, but is not a correct solution since it
         works only for that example `query`:
         def extract(query):
              return query("ab") + query("al") + query("altercation") + query("b") + query("el") + query("ev") + query("m")

         Your goal is to write an `extract` method that is correct for any provided `query`.
      """
      # YOUR CODE HERE
      return [...]

  def main():
      """Runs your solution -- no need to update 
         (except to maybe try out different databases)."""
      # Sample implementation of the autocomplete API
      database = ["abracadara", "al", "alice", "alicia", "allen", "alter",
                  "altercation", "bob", "element", "ello", "eve",
                  "evening", "event", "eventually", "mallory"]

      query = lambda prefix: [d for d in database if d.startswith(prefix)][:5]
      assert extract(query) == database

  main()
  ```

My Solution:

- Here is My solution where I use recursion to get the answer:

  ```
  def extract_api(results, base, start, maxi_len):
      if len(base) == maxi_len:
          return list(set(results))

      for i in range(start, 26):
          word = base + alphabets[i]
          query_results = query(word)
          results += query_results
          processed_results = list(set(results))
          processed_results.sort()
          if processed_results == database:
              return processed_results
          extract_api(results, word, i, maxi_len)

      return list(set(results))


  def main():
      global maximum_length
      for m in range(2, 26):
          res = (extract_api([], "", 0, m))
          maximum_length = m
          if res == database:
              break
      assert extract_api([], "", 0, maximum_length) == database


  database = ["abracadara", "al", "alice", "alicia", "allen", "alter", 
               "altercation", "bob", "element", "ello", "eve",
               "evening", "event", "eventually", "mallory"]

  alphabets = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
           "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
           "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

  maximum_length = 0
  query = lambda prefix: [d for d in database if d.startswith(prefix)][:5]

  main()
  ```
- My solution gives the correct answer but is very inefficient as it makes multiple api calls in order to find the right answer
- I think there has to be a way where I can take advantage of usernames being stored in lexicographical order to get an efficient solution
- Please provide a descriptive solution and not just the code. Thank you in advance

Comment: You posted this before the competition ended. It ended at the end of March 31st (11:59pm) and you posted this question WITH your solution at least 18 hours before that. :/

Comment: Ohh I thought is got over on 30th march.... I am extreme my sorry...I think i was too curious to know the answer... I feel bad now ... Sorry

Comment: if you want to see other solutions, I saw some of the participants post about theirs in the gist comments since it's over.